# Laravel run a group of middlewares with a specific guard

Tags: laravel, laratrust

I have two different guards **api** guard and **transporter** guard, I used laratrust package to manage the users roles and permissions

```
 Route::get('/requests', 'RequestController@index')->middleware('ability:owner|administrator,read-requests|all-requests');
```

I need to run the laratrust middlewares above only when the guard is **api** guard

**Note:-**
from laratrust docs
https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/middleware.html#concepts
I figured out that you can specify your guard like so but it did not work

```
  Route::get('/requests', 'RequestController@index')->middleware('ability:owner|administrator,read-requests|all-requests|guard:api');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Laratrust but if it's a middleware scoped to an entire route group, I think you can define it in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file in the `$middlewareGroups` array.

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        'ability:owner',
        'administrator',
        'read-requests',
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Laravel\Jetstream\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        'ability:owner',
        'administrator',
        'read-requests',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```